# Flyout theme property won't work in Mahapps

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro, app.xaml, flyout

My code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <Controls:Flyout Position="Right" Width="250" Theme="Inverse">
            <!--Content-->
        </Controls:Flyout>
    </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

For some reason my flyout won't change themes. I've tried doing it in the code behind but it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Found Issue

In App.xaml I apparently had deleted:

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />`

It doesn't matter what color the accent is set to, but if it isn't there the theme won't work. So I just added this tag back.